# How do you change the zoom level of the HUD map in BF3 on xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

I can see the HUD change when a mortar is deployed in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKesyy-eajc).  Is there a way to change the HUD zoom during the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to press start. Not enough buttons. And no, you cannot remap this on a console.

Answer (score 3):

On PC the keys are

- <kbd>n</kbd> to switch between small, medium, and large map **size**
- <kbd>m</kbd> to switch between small, medium, and large map **zoom**

I don't know the controller button equivalents for this, unfortunately!

I found this controller layout scheme

```
Left Bumper      Grenade
Left Trigger     ADS
Right Bumper     Melee, hold to equip knife
Right Trigger    Fire

Left Stick    Move
              Click once to enable run (continues until you release forward)
              Click and hold while ADS to steady aim (Recon)
Right Stick   Aim
              Click to duck, hold to prone

Y   Change Weapon
X   Reload
B   Enter/Leave Vehicle - Arm/Disarm M-Com
A   Jump/Vault 

Pad Up     Turn on/off torch (when unlocked)
Pad Left   Deploy Ammo/Med Pack/ Radio beckon/etc... (when unlocked)
Pad Right  Deploy Defib/Rocked Launcher/Motion Sensor/etc... (when unlocked)
Pad Down   Change rate of fire

Start      Options menu
Back       Spot (press), Score board (hold)
```

But wow, I don't see the map controls anywhere. Maybe they couldn't fit it in there? Can you remap controls on the Xbox? Perhaps there's a way to remap the map zoom/size functions to one of the existing buttons?

Comment: nice research, but does not answer the op directly. Are you saying HUD zoom is not possible?

Comment: if hud zoom in/out is possible on PC, i'm sure it is also possible on xbox.  now just have to figure out how and answer my own question.